# Find maximum and minimum argument of $f(z)=(z^4-1)/4$ where $z$ belongs to square with vertices $\{1,i,-1,-i\}$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, complex-numbers

let z be a complex number with |z|<1, 
now how to find the max and min argument of $(z^4-1)/4$

This original problem given below comes from kheavan.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/mathematical-olympiads-1997-1998-problems-solutions-from-around-the-world-maa-problem-book-225p-b002kypabi.pdf

(question number 1 section 1.9)

Do read the solution to understand what I am really asking.

[image]

Let P be a point inside or on the sides of a square ABCD. Determine
the minimum and maximum possible values of
f(P) = ∠ABP + ∠BCP + ∠CDP + ∠DAP.

I want the answer to my question, not to the original problem

Comment: I have taken the liberty to include the text of your exercise into your question for a better ease.

Answer (score 1):

Your function

$$f(z)=(z^4-1)/4$$

can be considered as the composition of 3 functions/transforms :

$$z \to z^4=u \mapsto u-1=v \mapsto v/4$$

the two last transforms are a translation and a homothety ("shrinking" from the origin with ratio 4:1)

The closed unit disk $C((0,0),1)$ is sent onto itself by the first transform (each point being reached 4 times). Then it is transformed into C((-1,0),1), and finally into $C((-\tfrac14,0),\tfrac14)$   itself (each point being reached 4 times as can be understood by seing the second figure).

---

Edit : I have had a look at the original question, with which I had some difficulty like you had. I understand now properly with the aid of a figure.

This figure represents the initial square with circumscribed unit circle ; and their images : no surprise for the image of the circle, but we couldn't truely await that the image of the square is a kind of droplet with limiting angles $3 \pi/4$ and $5 \pi/4$. All the vertices of the square are "mapped" on the apex of the drop : maybe you know that a complex transformation preserves the angles : the image of a $\pi/2$ angle remains a $\pi/2$ angle...

[image]

*Fig. 1 : The image by $f$ 1) of the unit circle is the small circle 2) of the square is the shape looking like a drop. See Fig. 2.*

Matlab program for the generation of this figure :

> ```
> clear all;close all;hold on;axis equal
> t=0:0.01:1;
> f=@(z)((z.^4-1)/4),
> for k=1:4
>    z=(i^k)*(t+(1-t)*i);plot(z,'b');plot(f(z),'b'); % 4 square's sides
> end;
> z=exp(2*pi*i*t);plot(z,'r');plot(f(z),'r')
> ```

In order to understand the mapping, here is a complementary representation displaying arrows joining $z$ to $f(z)$ for different values of $z$, either at the boundary of a quarter of circle (green arrows) or of a side of the square (blue arrows); please note for example that the midpoint of the side (any side in fact) of the square is mapped onto the bottom of the drop.

[image]

*Fig. 2 : Some examples of points $z$ and their resp. images $f(z)$ connected by an arrow. A quarter of the unit circle or a single side of the square are enough for defining the little circle and the drop.*

Comment: and what about (z^4-1)/4, what is the center and radius now

Comment: you mean center (1,0) right?

Comment: Yes I mean center $1+0i$, i.e., $(1,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: what would be maximum and minimum argument of (z^4-1)/4, as the asnwer is 225 degree and i cant figure out why

Comment: so why the answer of the original question mentioned in my post is 225 degree, plz look at the solution that is given on the link given     ,                                                              question number 1 section 1.9

Comment: I have had a look. The solution hasn't seem me very clear till I have made a figure using a (Matlab) program. I reproduce it as an edit to my answer.

Comment: The question asks that $|z|<1$.  If $z=1$ were allowed, then yes, the locus could achieve an angle of $\arg f(z) =0$ (or $\arg f(z) = 2\pi$).  Since $|z|=1$ is not allowed, the solutions are all in the left-half plane.

Comment: You are looking for the arguments of the $z$ that are inside the droplet. You can have all possible results with $3 \pi/4 < arg(z) < 5 \pi/4$ ; I agree that the bounds are not reached (one should use the terms "sup" and "inf" instead of max and min).

Comment: so are you saying that the locus of (z^4-1)/4 with condition |Z|<1 is inside the droplet. if yes then I dont get it, I thought the locus was inside the smaller circle, and if the smaller circle is the locus than what is the droplet, and could you explain this line ["but we couldn't truely await that the image of the square is a kind of droplet"] or just rephrase it in simpler english ( as english is not my first language)

Comment: In fact, the border of the droplet is traversed 4 times, The image of side AB by the function is the totality of the border of the droplet. The same for the other sides.  [this is what I called "non-awaited"]. If I have some time, I will try do produce a more detailed figure in order to understand what happens.

Comment: I have no clue what you are talking about mate, you are using too many technical terms which I am not familiar with, I have no clue what that droplet is and what does it represent. you might have you restart from the scratch and explain using simpler language

Comment: I have added a new graphical representation to my answer.

Comment: awesome! so here is what i have undestood  1) locus of (z^4-1)/4 with condition |z|<1 is the smaller circle      2) locus of (z^4-1)/4 with condition z lies inside the square is the droplet. and the sup of argument of z lies inside the droplet is 225 degree.

Comment: now the question arises that how can one find the locus of (z^4-1)/4 with condition z lies inside the square with out using a program, as during a exam you cant use a program.

Comment: As said by Shakespeare : "that is the question"...

Comment: lol! thanks for helping man, one question why do people answer on such site, do they get paid if yes then how does the site earn, I see do ads? I know its not the right place to ask but I ask it anyway

Comment: No, nobody is paid. It is based on good willingness to help people. Besides, I have no idea of the economical model of this site. (Some branches have ads)